How can I create such a block using flex or grid?
I want to create a block that contains 3 main elements: a header, a list, and a chart. When the screen width drops below a certain value, I want the order of the elements to change. Here's how it should look:

Here are the requirements:

.chart should have a minimum height.
.chart__datasets can have any height depending on the number of items.
.chart__canvas should always maintain a 1:1 aspect ratio (only on large screens).
.chart__datasets and .chart__canvas should always be horizontally centered within the block.
.chart__datasets should take up 70% of .chart width, and the .chart__canvas 30%.
There should be at least a 20px gap between the .chart__header and the .chart__datasets.

I have created a basic layout. I used flex for everything. The header has position: absolute, and I wrapped the list and the chart in a div with the class chart__body and centered them relative to each other within it. But there's an issue: if the list (dataset) has a large height, it starts overlapping with the header, and I don't know how to fix this yet.


html, body, .page {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #ecf0f1;
}

.chart {
  width: 450px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  min-height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #7f8c8d;
}

.chart__title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 15px;
  background: #3498db;
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
}

.chart__body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  column-gap: 15px;
}

.chart__datasets {
  width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f1c40f;
}
  
.chart__canvas {
  background: #2ecc71;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .chart__body {
    margin-top: 60px;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    align-items: normal;
    row-gap: 15px;
  }
  .chart__datasets {
    width: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  .chart__canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
  }
}
<div class="page">
<div class="chart">
  <h3 class="chart__title"></h3>
  <div class="chart__body">
    <div class="chart__datasets">
      
    </div>
    <div class="chart__canvas">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>




Why do you need your chart_title to be absolute ?

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

@Paulie_D Okay, I get it. I didn't use the built-in snippet because there was no way to add scss code.

@VincentDecaux Because if this is not done, then .chart__datasets and .chart__canvas will not be centered on the .chart. They will be below the center by the height of the .chart__header

Don’t absolutely position your title.
After running this snippet, use the full page link to test it.


html, body, .page {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #ecf0f1;
}

.chart {
  width: 450px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  min-height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #7f8c8d;
}

.chart__title {
  background: #3498db;
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.chart__body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  column-gap: 15px;
  padding-bottom: calc(25px + 1em);
}

.chart__datasets {
  width: 70%;
  background: #f1c40f;
  color: white;
}
  
.chart__canvas {
  background: #2ecc71;
  width: 30%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .chart__body {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    align-items: normal;
    row-gap: 15px;
  }
  .chart__datasets {
    width: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  .chart__canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
  }
}
<div class="page">
<div class="chart">
  <h3 class="chart__title"></h3>
  <div class="chart__body">
    <div class="chart__datasets">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.
    </div>
    <div class="chart__canvas">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>




This works, but if you reduce the size of .chart__datasets now, you will see that .chart__datasets and .chart__canvas are not centered on .chart, because .chart__header shifts them. Therefore, I absolutely positioned .chart__header

Okay, I have updated the snippet to add some bottom padding to .chart to balance the title (height 25px) and its bottom margin (1em) — padding-bottom: calc(25px + 1em). If you want this adjustment on the mobile view only, you can move this declaration to your @media rule.
